# Setting up a Production Server for Rails

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am currently installing Ubuntu Server 10.04 in a virtual machine and I am going to run my web app in it so I can see how it runs, etc in a 'production' environment.

What software should be installed and what is the common software/packages installed when hosting a Rails app?

In my real production environment, I am running Ubuntu Server 10.04 64bit, Apache2, PHP5, MySQL and am using Virtualmin to manage the setup on these sites, therefore I want it to imitate the real production web server as it will be deployed to that when the app is ready.

I have installed Passenger on my real production web server. I am just looking for software that I should install in my clean Ubuntu Server.

EDIT: Also is it recommended to use RVM in production?

Answer (score 2):

[Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) with the Apache module (since you are already running Apache).  I'd use [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage your Ruby VM.  Use Ruby 1.9.2 if possible.  There are instructions on the RVM site for [using RVM with Passenger.](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/)

Comment: OK cool. I am looking to learn and use Capistrano as well. Could I run the rvm install script, run the `bundle:install` and `rake db:migrate` through the script? I ask this because virtualmin creates a new user for each domain and stores the files in `/home/domain/public_html`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I would **try to mimic the actual production environment** you're targeting.

Depending on your project, **add required dependencies for your *Rails* app** to your current stack.

As to **RVM**, yes. I think it's worth to add it to your setup now. It may seem as an unnecessary burden at first, but in the long run you will save yourself a lot of hassle, especially if you begin to host other *Rails* apps later on.

Comment: What I meant was what software should be installed to run Rails, but it doesn't matter now as I have the main setup done. And OK, I will use RVM from now on in production as well. I use it on my Mac for developing the apps and it's very useful to have the separate gemsets so they don't conflict with each other